# Non-blocking tornado instance on Openshift?

Tags: python, tornado, openshift-origin

I am trying to create tornado webserver and quick start made me standard project of tornado, but according to documentation this configuration is blocking.
I am new to non-blocking python.

I have this wsgi file that lies in root folder in my PAAS server

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import imp
import sys

#
# Below for testing only
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ip   = 'localhost'
    port = 8051
    zapp = imp.load_source('application', 'wsgi/application')

    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    httpd = make_server(ip, port, zapp.application)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

This is main handler file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
     def get(self):
          self.render('index.html')
```

And Application folder contains this

```
# Put here yours handlers.
import tornado.wsgi
from . import handlers

handlers = [(r'/',MainHandler),]


application = tornado.wsgi.WSGIApplication(handlers, **settings)
```

[In WSGI mode asynchronous methods are not supported](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html)

[uses WSGI to deploy the python applications](https://github.com/rancavil/tornado-openshift-quickstart)

Is it possible to configure python application on openshift to be fully non-blocking

[Though i have seen project that seemed to work](https://github.com/avinassh/openshift-tornado-starter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about OpenShift V2 (not V3 which uses Kubernetes/Docker), then you need to use the `app.py` file as described in:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/08/running-async-web-applications-under.html

Comment: V3 is (next gen) web console? I guess i am V2.
I wasn't sure that i can change webserver from mod-wsgi or any other uWsgi to tornado.
Thanks!